# Pyspark : Unable to import csv file in Zeppilin instance

Tags: csv, import, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm unable to run following line of code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df_t = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('s3a://Bucket_name/Train - Copy.csv')
```

it throws below error:

```
AnalysisException: u'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
```

I tried restarting the interpreter but no help.

Can someone please help with this issue?

Thanks,
Naseer

Comment: on restarting the interpreter: I'm getting this issue AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: s3a://bucketname/train_45_var.csv;'

Answer (score 0):

It seems, hive metastore is not running, you can try starting the service

```
hive --service metastore
```

you can use following code, to read csv which doesn't use SQLContext

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Reading CSV") \
    .getOrCreate()

df_t = spark.read.csv('s3a://Bucket_name/Train - Copy.csv',header=True, inferSchema=True)
df_t.show()
```

Comment: I only have access to zepplin notebook where i can perform my operations on imported csv. In such instance, how can i start the service
i see the hive command doesn't work.
moreover, the session code also doesn't work.